# Java REST service binary downloads

Tags: java, objective-c, web-services, tomcat, download

I have a java REST web service that is currently downloading text files to an iPad application. We are wanting to extend the service to now download 10 - 20 Mb of binary data at one time from multiple requests. These requests are will range from a few kb to to a few Mbs. How we have it setup now, the download is not very efficient and most of the time the download does not finish. Does anyone have any suggestions on resources or a plan of action?

Thanks

Edit to provide some more information. The current setup is tomcat web server just with no extra frameworks. I pass in a URL to get a bunch of insert statements and about 40ish links to download blob data. Then I make those 40 requests 2 at a time until the process is complete. I have tried more than 2 requests, but it usually fails a lot sooner with client did close connection errors. The database where the binary data is stored is SQLite.

Is there any other information needed to help?

Comment: Please provide more details on what's not working well and why you think this is ... What is the current setup?

Comment: Have you tested from a normal web browser? Could the problem be in the part that reads the blob from sqlite? Have you evaluated an alternative to 40Mb blobs?

Comment: @SimoneGianni Unfortunately the blobs are mandatory. I would not have gone this way, but it is what I'm stuck with. I have increased the performance of the query with some caching when my java app starts up instead of query the database directly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should easily work with Apache Tomcat. I have developed several apps on iOS that download data from the server via multiple requests (images, JSON, and XML). I think the problem might be in the iOS App. Are you making multiple requests from your app in seperate threads? iOS does not like the UI thread to be blocked for network operations.

Comment: I am using ASIHttpRequest library to download. This is using their own flavor of nsopeartionqueue. I think the main problem is that if there are a lot of requests tomcat will put the users in a queue, but that increases the wait time to even begin downloading the data.